# Creating Shader Resource View performance

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-12

I was wondering if its considered an "okay" practice to create a shader resource view for a `ID3D12Resource` just before passing it into a `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList` and destroying it afterward when the frame completes?

Do note that I create the descriptor view for the said resource only once.

Comment: Why are you rendering it only a single time?

Comment: I don't. The graphics abstraction library I'm doing makes it so that texture resources and shader resources are not tightly coupled. For APIs like DX11 I do create the SRV upon texture resource creation since this was the way to do it before AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quote from a Microsoft engineer about why CreateShaderResourceView return void and not an error code.

> We intentionally don't have return codes on high frequency APIs since it would be a waste of CPU time to be checking for errors every call, which could be happening on the fly many thousands of times a frame.

They assume by design that it is an api that can be called many times a frame, the answer to your question is, yes, you can do it, it is not a problem.

You just have to be careful to protect the view lifetime in the descriptor heap for as long as the gpu may need it before overwriting it.